# Laravel policy always returns 403

Tags: laravel

so I made a policy and whatever I do the Web page returns 403. im very new to laravel so most likely im missing something :)

I made a model by
`php artisan make:model exercise` | (I know I'm supposed to capitalize models but it was a typo)

Controller:

```
php artisan make:controller ExercisesController
```

Policy:

```
php artisan make:policy ExercisePolicy -m exercise
```

I registered policy in AuthServiceProvider.php (Also tried as 'App\Models\exercise'=>'App\Policies\ExercisePolicy'):

```
 protected $policies = [
    // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    exercise::class => ExercisePolicy::class,
];
```

In ExercisesController.php this is the function in which I use authentication:

```
public function create(\App\Models\User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('create', $user);
    return view('exercises/create');
}
```

And in policy this is how my create function looks like

```
public function create(User $user)
{
    return $user->admin == true;
}
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/exercises/create', [App\Http\Controllers\ExercisesController::class, 'create']);
```

I tried putting die("Policy is called); and trying to just return true from the policy create function to check if it gets to that but it still returned 403 , at this point I'm pretty sure that the policy itself is not being called as it also returns 403 on default

If anyone could help thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call to `authorize` is using the second argument to figure out what Policy to use. Since the second argument is `$user` it would be looking for a Policy for the User model which you have not defined. To use the Policy for the `exercise` model you would have to pass the class name so it would know what Policy to use:

```
$this->authorize('create', exercise::class);
```

Though you should correct your typo and rename the `exercise.php` file to `Exercise.php` and the classname to `Exercise`.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Authorization - Writing Policies - Methods without Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#methods-without-models)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Authorization - Authorization Actions using Policies - Via Controller Helpers - Actions That Don't Require Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#controller-actions-that-dont-require-models)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and what I learnt was that Policies would work only on authenticated route.

Make sure your request is authenticated while implementing policies.

Comment: hey you can have guest policies [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#guest-users).